# What's the best Yii way of getting data from 2 tables?

Tags: php, mysql, yii, yii2, active-record-query

I want to get data based on 2 db tables

There is:

```
 course table
 student_in_course table (with foreign key course_id)
```

I would like to get all `course.name`

based on `student_in_course.course_id` 
for a specific `student_in_course.student_id`

What's the best practice of doing it with ActiveRecord (or other recommended way)?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not just do it in the SQL statement?

Comment: I'm new to Yii but I see there are many ready to use methods regarding views and more, It would be nice to learn a new good way of doing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yii2 documentation suggests to use 'joinWith' in case you need to perform a left join query with Active record. So in your case you'd want something like this:

```
$courses = Course::find()
  ->select('course.name')
  ->joinWith('student_in_course')
  ->where(['student_in_course.student_id' => $student_id])
  ->all();
```

Please refer to [Yii2 official docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html).

Answer (score 3):

First of all, ActiveRecord is the best approach if you are going to work with YII, seems like you are going to use a cross-reference table use `via()` or `viaTable()`.

```
class Student extends ActiveRecord{

     public function getStudentsInCourses() {
          return $this->hasMany(StudentInCourses::className(), ['student_id' => 'id']);
      }

     public function getCourses() {
          return $this->hasMany(Course::className(), ['id' => course_id'])
                   ->via('studentsInCourses');
     }
}
```

Comment: +1 voteup , for mentioning `viaTable()` as it reuses relations and prevents you from filling up your models with extra SQL queries.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `ActiveRecord` is what I would prefer doing it with,but the thing is if you are going to display in `GridView` or `ListView` using `activeDataProvider` sometime you might need to update/ adjust the query in serachModel rather than writing a separate function with a query in the `model` or as some people do write inside controller's action, until unless if you are using a custom view and displaying it manually and want the result set as an `array` or `activedataprovider` object to iterate on it and display records then the answer suggested by `@GiulioG` is applicable. But the thing to be noticed in both the scenarios is that you should define appropriate `relations` and you do not need to use `joins` manually.